# Redirecting to a specific page if the visitor used a certain name to resolve the server address

Tags: nginx

How can I get visitors redirected to a specific html page if the name used to resolve the server address was a specific one? I tried

```
if ($http_host ~ /forbiddenname/)
{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /updateyourlinks.html break;
}
```

inside the Server section, but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that I should use instead of an if a virtual host... what I've added to nginx configuration is another server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.badname.com;
    rewrite ^ http://goodname.com/updateyourlinks.html;
}
```

and this apparently works